# How to add up a url link to each image?

Tags: html, css, slider

Hi I just copy this simple CSS slider code from the website, can anyone tells me how to add url link to each image in this slider code? I tried to add "a href" to each image but its not working I wonder why...:( thank you so much for the help~

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/13/9f/39/d1/cape-view-clifton.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 12s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 12s infinite;

} 
.slide2 {
  background: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/13/9f/39/e3/cape-view-clifton.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade2 12s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 12s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
    background: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/13/9f/39/db/outside-sun-deck.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 12s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 12s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 1}
  66.666% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 1}
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you want to do with the link.

Given the code in the question it is possible to change the divs that are the images into a (anchor) tags - they will take on the same background images and dimensions.

In a real situation it is likely that the clicked link would open a new window but note that the SO snippet system does not allow that so in this snippet you can see the pointer changing which shows there is a link, but it doesn't go anywhere.

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/13/9f/39/d1/cape-view-clifton.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 12s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 12s infinite;

} 
.slide2 {
  background: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/13/9f/39/e3/cape-view-clifton.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade2 12s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 12s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
    background: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/13/9f/39/db/outside-sun-deck.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 12s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 12s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 1}
  66.666% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 1}
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide1"></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide2"></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide3"></a>
</div>
```